# Routing traffic to specific VM's via load balancer on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, network-programming, google-cloud-networking, gcp-load-balancer

I am new to Google Cloud Platform and advanced networking in general but I have been tasked with setting up an external HTTPS load balancer that can forward internet traffic to 2 separate Virtual Machines on the same VPC. I have created the load balancer, SSL certs, DNS, frontend, and a backend. I have also created an instance group containing the two VM's for use with the backend.

What I am failing to understand is, how do I determine which VM is going to receive the traffic? Example:

- I want test.com/login to go to instance1/some/path/login.php
- I want test.com/download to go to instance2/some/path/file.script

  Any help is greatly appreciated here. Thanks

Comment: Look into URL Maps. However, load balancer means "balance" not direct. Create separate instance groups when you want to direct traffic. There are lots of configuration possibilities. Review how load balancers and instance groups (managed and unmanaged) are configured. Then rewrite your question into a problem that we can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detail what @John Hanley mentioned in configuring URL maps, you can follow these steps :

1. On you load balancer balancer page. Click the name of the load balancer, then look for Edit.
2. Select `Host and path rules`, then click `Add host and path rule`.

On the host field, enter `test.com/login`. Then for your path, `instance1/some/path/login.php`.

3. Once done, for the `Backends`, select the backend associated to the VM instance. Do the same step for `test.com/download`by adding another host and path rule.
4. Click Update.

You can check and refer to this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map#configure_url_maps) for more details